# The map is not firing correctly when it is fired

Tags: javascript, reactjs

During my render function, I am trying to display a list based on an array, and while displaying it works well, whatever event I bind to it appears to be ignored.

```
render: function() {
  var language = function(language) {
    return (
      <li><label>
        <input type="checkbox" value={language} onChange={this.onLanguageChange} /> 
        {language} ({_languages_total[language]})
      </label></li>
    )
  }

  return (
    <ul className="filter__list">
      <li><label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="0" onChange={this.onLanguageChange} />
        0 (2)
      </label></li>
      {this.state.languages.map(language)}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Comment: You want to set `this` to the component within your `language` function: `this.state.languages.map(language, this)`. Or you can change `language` to be an arrow function so that `this` is grabbed from the outer scope.